# Not sure why members of character array not printing properly in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *input[1000];
    char *word;
int i = 0;
while (scanf("%s", word) != EOF)
{
    input[i] = word;
    i++;
}
printf("%s ", input[0]);
printf("%s ", input[1]);
printf("%s ", input[2]);
}
```

for example, if the input is "My name is", the output would be "is is is" as opposed to "My name is". Can anyone point out where in my code is wrong.

Comment: Or perhaps, what is a better way to code a program that reads a series of words from stdin and stores it in an array?

Comment: Is this a test? Because [a question with exactly the same code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218216/can-anyone-please-explain-how-the-following-loop-executes) just got deleted.

Comment: no, its a bunch of practice questions

Comment: And the purpose of the practice is what, to detect the bugs?

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues here, let me try to address them

with the following you are declaring an array of char pointers
but those pointers are not pointing anywhere or rather they are
pointing everwhere ;-).

```
char *input[1000];
```

now you declare a pointer, which left uninitialized, points anywhere

```
char *word;
```

now you read from the keyboard using the uninitialized pointer

```
while (scanf("%s", word) != EOF)
```

What you need to do allocate memory for what you read

First have a temporary buffer to read from the keyboard

```
char word[100];
```

Now while reading from the keyboard copy the contents of word and allocate
memory for the contents.

```
input[i++] = strdup(word);
```

Do not forget to free the memory that input[] are pointing too, it is also
good if you initialize the input[] pointers so you can distringuish between
used pointers and uninitialized pointers.

```
char* input[1000] = { NULL };
```

Comment: And to prevent buffer overflow, limit the reading of the word by changing %s to %100s, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c

Comment: @Roalt yep, good point. personally i would have used fgets instead since it is anyway just strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated memory for `word`. The code invokes undefined behavior.
Allocate some memory like this:

```
int stringSize = 10;
char *word = malloc(sizeof(char)*stringSize );
```

or

```
char  word [10];
```

Comment: Ok, i see what you mean. How can I fix it to get the desired output?

Comment: All the inputs points at the memory address of word currently, right?

Comment: Is there another way to do it without malloc. This hasn't been covered yet.

Comment: You could use `char word[20];` . But then the line `input[i] = word;` will fail. So you do not have much choice really, you have to either use malloc, or use `char input[1000][20];` instead too.

Answer (score 0):

word is a pointer to an array of chars, which will point to your first input "My" on the first iteration. This means that:

```
word = "My";
input[0] = word;
input[0] = "My"; //as word and input[0] now point to the same memory location
```

You're then modifying the value stored at the location in memory pointed to by word:

```
input[0] = word;
word = "name";
input[1] = word;
```

word, as a pointer has not changed, only the value it points to has changed. On your second iteration:

```
input[0] = word = "name"; //as the memory location of word doesn't change
input[1] = word = "name"; //any pointer set to word will point to the same char array
```

Your third iteration does the exact same thing, causing your output to be "is is is".

First, you should define word with its own size/memory:

```
char word[64] = NULL; //arbitrary size that's bigger than your largest length word
```

For this example you can use:

```
char input[5][64] = { NULL };
```

But I would suggest using dynamically allocated memory for input later on.

And it's up to you how you copy the contents of word to your input array, but possibilities include using strcpy:

```
int i = 0;
while (scanf("%s", word) != EOF){
    strcpy(input[i], (const char*)word);
    i++;
}
```